# Unable to read checkbox value in cucumber

Tags: ruby, checkbox, cucumber

I am new to automation (Cucumber), and has very less idea of coding. I am looking for the script through which I can click on checkbox or radiobutton. Below is the HTML code I am looking at:

```
<"input class="facetoption" type="checkbox" value="facets.price_range%5B%5D=Rs.+2000+and+Below" autocomplete="off">
```

And below is the step definition which I tried

```
Step definition:

Then(/^Select the first Price Range Option$/) do
  @browser.checkbox(:value => 'facets.price_range5B%5D=Rs.+2000+and+Below').click
end
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The value in your locator doesn't match the value in the `<input>` tag.  Compare the strings, and you'll see they are different.

your HTML: `"facets.price_range%5B%5D=Rs.+2000+and+Below"`

your code: `"facets.price_range5B%5D=Rs.+2000+and+Below"`

Update your step definition to the following, and it should work:

```
Then(/^Select the first Price Range Option$/) do
  @browser.checkbox(:value =>'facets.price_range%5B%5D=Rs.+2000+and+Below').click
end
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't know why you try to find checkbox by value. Better option is to find checkbox by id or class:

```
find('input#id').click()
```

If you still like to find checkbox by value please use:

```
find(:xpath, "input[@value='John']").click()
```

Answer (score 0):

Use a regex so you can focus on the imporant parts, and ignore the unimporant parts

```
@browser.checkbox(:value => /2000\+and\+Below/).click
```